# Gzip the PDF and then do Base64 encoding in Java

Tags: java

Input to my code is Base64 content of a PDF.

I want to Base 64 decode it and then 7z gzip and again Base64 encode of gzipped file.
(I just need the Base64 of actual 7z Gzipped PDF file)

I tired this but not working (It gives an output string but it is not matching with the manually generated one, that is the correct base64 string)

```
String b64 = "-...";
  byte[] decoder = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64);

  try {
      Base64OutputStream b64os = new Base64OutputStream(System.out);
      GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(b64os);
      gzip.write(decoder);
      gzip.close();
      b64os.close();
  } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
  }
```

variable `String b64` has the actual PDF base64 content

Comment: Can you provide more details about the problem, please? Do you get any exceptions? What is "not working"?

Comment: @Mihe It gives an output string but it is not matching with the manually generated one, that is the correct base64 string

Comment: @Sahal I believe there are different equally valid ways to 'gzip a file'.

Comment: @mihe, requirement is to 7zip gzip

Comment: @Sahal, 7zip (LZMA)? You'd need a library for that, gzip is included in Java SE. BTW: there are different Base64 encodings, too (URL safe alphabet, standard alphabet, fixed width with \r\n as end of line terminator.

Comment: @mihe can you please suggest one library please

Comment: @Sahal, haven't used one but a quick search at Google revelaed that there's a SDK at https://7-zip.org/sdk.html, and Maven Central hosts https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.sevenzipjbinding

Comment: From [the gzip manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip): “By default, gzip keeps the original file name and timestamp in the compressed file.”  As far as I know, GZIPOutputStream does not do that.  That alone would account for differences in the output.